# gitlab conditional scan inclusion

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline

Have the below code for conditional scans inclusion

```
variables:
  ## Debug and other convenience variables
  SKIP_SCANS: "true"


include:
  - project: "blah/gitlab-ci-templates"
    file: "/templates/sonarqube.gitlab-ci.yml"
    ref: "blahblah/1.0.8"
    rules:
      - if: ${SKIP_SCANS} !~ /true/i
```

But , this works on automated pipeline launch during commits ( observing that the scans are skipped as expected )

However on manual pipeline run with SKIP_SCANS set to false , the pipeline still does'nt include the stage ?

Comment: What does `/true/i` represents?

Comment: trying to match ```true``` with ignore case

Comment: Did you test with a simple case to be sure the rule is working, then use this regex?

Comment: it works because on new commits the pipeline goes off automatically and does'nt include those scans as expected since the variable is set to ```false``` , my problem is it does'nt include the scans when the variable is set to ```true``` when the pipeline is invoked manually ?

Comment: First, I got a syntax error with the rule `${SKIP_SCANS} !~ /true/i`.  Replaced with `$SKIP_SCANS !~ /true/i`

Comment: It also worked as expected
https://gitlab.com/monegim/test-ci/-/jobs/3963339859#L25

Comment: Hmm thanks for checking out , the issue is it doesn't work as expected when used with includes...with boolean false on manual pipeline execution , seeing the scan not getting included and doesn't show as a stage